# Reformatting with neovim LSP and clangd adds double carriage return (^M) on line breaks

Tags: neovim, lsp

I am using neovim (0.6) and its built-in LSP with clangd-12 for C++.  When reformatting a file that uses DOS-style line endings, it for some reason uses a double carriage return, resulting in one `^M` to show up in the editor.

To illustrate:  I have the following file (output with `cat -A` to show the line endings):

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])^M$
{^M$
    int foo = 42; return 0;^M$
}^M$
```

After reformatting with `vim.lsp.buf.formatting()`, it looks like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])^M$
{^M$
    int foo = 42;^M^M$
    return 0;^M$
}^M$
```

Note the `^M^M` in the line break caused by the formatting.

This does not happen, when I run `clang-format-12` on the file, so it seems to be related to the nvim/lsp setup rather than to the clang-format configuration.

Any idea what could be the problem here?

In case it's relevant, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Probably the LSP somehow doesn't know (or didn't take into account?) the DOS-endings. Odd that it should only happen on one line… at any rate, I suspect your best bet at solving this lies with the LSP-client maintainers.

Comment: It only happens on the line breaks that are added by the reformatting, existing ones are not changed.